# volttron.platform.web INFO: Web server not started

Tags: python, eclipse, volttron

When I try to run volttron through Eclipse it gives me this message at the end:

```
volttron.platform.web INFO: Web server not started
```

In the run configurations, the arguments I gave at first was `-vv --developer-mode`. It didn't recognize it, neither did it recognise `-vv -developer-mode`. The message was:

```
usage: main.py [OPTION]...
main.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --developer-mode
```

When I remover developer-mode it gives me the first message.
I am using Ubuntu, Luna eclipse.

Comment: the web server not start is normal.  The only time you would have a web server is if you specified the bind-web-address in the instance config file or via the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Developer mode has been removed and is no longer needed.

To achieve the equivalent of the old developer mode do this:

```
volttron-ctl auth add
```

Leave ever answer blank except for this:

```
credentials []: /.*/
```

This will setup the platform to allow agents to connect without proper credentials which is needed for running an agent in a debugger.

You can find out more here: http://volttron.readthedocs.io/en/develop/devguides/agent_development/index.html

The web server message is just informing you that the VOLTTRON platform web server is not setup to start. This is not an error condition.

Th web server is used for platform discovery, the common agent restful API, and a few other features, none of which required for normal operation.